# Templates Grafo C++

Tags: c++

Hola buenos días estoy repasando para un examen y estaba rehaciendo las practicas de mi universidad. En una de ella consiste en crear un grafo templatizado donde el nodo tendrá el nombre/letra del nodo y sus coordenadas x e y.

Para hacer la practica creé tres clases la de Dato: que albergará el nombre/letra y las coordenadas x,y; la clase Nodo que va a tener el Dato y sus demás funciones; y la clase Grafo que tendrá unidos los nodos.

De lo que sé de plantillas solo se templatizan tipos como int, string, double... pero en la solución del profesor él templatizó la clase Nodo. Si nodo es una estructura, ¿por qué la templatizó?

```
template <class T>
class Node
{

public:
    Node<T>(T d);

    T getData() const;
    void setData(T value);

    set<Node<T> *> getNeighbours() const;
    void setNeighbours(const set<Node<T> *> &value);

    float getPathWeight() const;
    void setPathWeight(float value);

    Node<T> *getPrev() const;
    void setPrev(Node<T> *value);

    bool getVisited() const;

    void printAll();
    void resetVisited();
    void addNeighbour(Node<T> *n);

    Node<T>* computePath(Node<T>* dest);
    Node<T>* computeDijkstraPath(Node<T>* dest, set<Node<T>*> & allNodes);
    Node<T>* computeAStar(Node<T> *dest, set<Node<T> *> &allNodes);

    void printPath();

protected:
    set<Node<T> *> neighbours;
    T data;
    bool visited;
    Node<T>* next;
    Node<T>* prev;
    float pathWeight;
    float distanceTo(Node<T>* n);

};
```

PD: la clase Dato no la tengo templatizada

```
class Data
{
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream & os, Data const & d);

public:
    Data(string _let, int _x, int _y);

    int getX() const;
    void setX(int value);

    int getY() const;
    void setY(int value);

    string getLetra() const;
    void setLetra(string value);

protected:
    int x,y;
    string letra;
};
```

Gracias.

Comment: ¿podrías poner algo de código que respalde la pregunta?

Answer (score 2):

> De lo que sé de plantillas solo se templatizan tipos como int, string, double

Esta afirmación es **falsa**. Una plantilla no es más que un molde. Ese molde puedes utilizarlo para crear clases con `int`, con `float` y demás tipos nativos, claro, pero también podría crear clases con `POO`, con `MiClaseFavorita` incluso con funciones.

De hecho no hay más que mirar la STL para comprobar este hecho. La clase `std::vector`, por ejemplo, es una plantilla que permite crear contenedores de elementos desordenados. Esta plantilla se puede usar con prácticamente cualquier tipo de objeto:

```
std::vector<int> listaDeEnteros;
std::vector<std::string> listaDeCadenas;

struct MiEstructura
{
};

std::vector<MiEstructura> otraLista;

std::vector<std::function<void()>> listaDeFunciones;
```

De hecho una plantilla puede especializarse con **otra plantilla**:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> listaDeListasDeEnteros;
```

En tu caso en concreto `Node` puede usarse de la misma manera, de tal forma que la lista podrá contener el tipo de dato que desees / necesites en cada momento.

> ¿por qué la templatizó?

Para tu ejemplo concreto podría no haberlo hecho. Pero al templatizar la estructura permites que pueda ser utilizada con tipos de datos diferentes.

Como norma general, los algoritmos y clases de uso genérico suelen implementarse como plantillas para facilitar la reutilización de su código.

> la clase Dato no la tengo templatizada

Ni falta que hace. Una cosa es la lista y otra la información que contiene dicha lista.

En tu caso, `Data` no necesita ser una plantilla simplemente porque no tienes ninguna necesidad de dejar que `Data` se adapte a tipos diferentes de los dados inicialmente.